# What Difference between power BI premium and power BI Embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

Can any one help me to explain difference between power BI premium and power BI Embedded?

Answer (score 13):

Power BI Embedded capacity (a.k.a. A SKUs) is [billed hourly](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/), can be purchased hourly, and can be paused – meaning no long-term commitments to a specific capacity. Power BI Premium (a.k.a. EM and P SKUs) are billed monthly, has annual commitment (i.e. you can't buy it for a month or two) and can't be paused. Premium also comes with [more capacity workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-what-is#capacity-workloads) attached to it (like AI (Cognitive Services), Dataflows, and Paginated reports, etc., while Dataset workload is supported in all), most important with Premium readers doesn't need Pro licenses, while the corresponding Embedded SKUs (A4+) will not give you that:

[image]

You may also take a look at [What is the difference between the A SKUs in Azure and the EM SKUs in Office 365?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq#what-is-the-difference-between-the-a-skus-in-azure-and-the-em-skus-in-office-365)

Comment: Can i switch from embedded to Premium and how report and dashboard etc I can move to premium.

Comment: You can use both. It's simply a matter of purchasing a dedicated capacity. You can buy as many capacities as you want. Using them is matter of attaching a capacity to a workspace, so you don't need to move your reports and dashboards, just assign the capacity you want to your workspace. See [Assigning workspaces to capacities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-capacity-manage#assigning-workspaces-to-capacities) section for more information.

Comment: Do you means suppose I brought Embedded plan now i want to move on premium the no need to move report and dashboard ETC right? Just i need to purchasing a dedicated capacity.

Comment: Do you mean suppose I purchased Embedded plan now I want to move on premium and vice versa then no need to move report and dashboard correct? 
I am asking because I saw Migration tool from Power BI Embedded to Power BI Service. What does that useful for?
Here is the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/migrate-tool

Comment: No, you don't need to use any migration tool. This "Power BI Embedded" that is mentioned is something old, working with "workspace collections", which are deprecated (not sure, but maybe even unavailable already). If you buy Power BI Embedded now, your reports will be stored in a normal workspace, to which you can assign either Power BI Embedded capacity (A1, A2, A3, etc.) or Power BI Premium capacity (P1, P2, P3).

Comment: Please confirm if this is still accurate: I understand this quote _"Premium readers doesn't need Pro licenses, while the corresponding Embedded SKUs (A4+) will not give you that"_ like this: Power BI Embedded capacity with A SKUs cannot be used to embed content in a public webpage to readers without Power BI license. But this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core) states:  _"To use your application, your users won't need to sign in to Power BI **or have a Power BI license**."_ Did that change? Thanks a lot for a hint!

Comment: @spikey The tutorial you mentioned implements embedding of Power BI elements, which **do not** need any kind of Power BI login, thus the end-users do not need any Power BI license. The difference is when the users consume the content either directly in the browser (e.g. when a report is shared with them), or when they use User-Owns-Data (embed for my organization) scenario. Then they are logging in using their own credentials and licenses, and then if the capacity is P SKU, users can consume content even with Free license (A SKU still require Pro license).

Answer (score 2):

In general, Power BI Premium is a SaaS (Software as a Service) product that allows users to consume content through mobile apps, internally developed apps, or at the Power BI portal. Power BI Embedded is for ISV(Independent Software Vendor)s who want to embed visuals into their applications. This is just basic understanding but coming to the real time business/organizational needs, one should know how they differ with the services they provide and billing/licensing part So, pls check out the below MS docs.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-faq#:~:text=Power%20BI%20Premium%20is%20a,embed%20visuals%20into%20their%20applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-faq#:%7E:text=Power%20BI%20Premium%20is%20a,embed%20visuals%20into%20their%20applications).

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Embedded is focused on getting users outside of your organization access to your data without giving them each a Power BI Pro license. This is generally done via the application you provide to them, allowing you to embed the dashboards you create into your application allowing for row level security and other features to be managed by the application and your developers.

Power BI Premium is more focused on giving people within your organization access to your reports without having to assign them all a Pro license. For the end users it works exactly the same as just having a standard license. In the backend you get dedicated processing capacity for your organization only which can be scaled up.

Please also note they are billed differently as Power BI Embedded is set up through the Azure Portal where as Premium is done through the Power BI Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Premium is capacity geared toward enterprises who want a complete BI solution that provides a single view of its organization, partners, customers, and suppliers.
Power BI Embedded helps your customers make decisions because Power BI Embedded is for application developers, customers of that application can consume content stored on Power BI Embedded capacity, including anyone inside or outside the organization.
[https://learn.microsoft.com]

Answer (score -1):

In simple manner, Power bi premium is service which provided by the power bi Microsoft and it has a great feature to play with in. on the other side power bi embedded is a feature of the power bi services which provide you to link with the browser or internet. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Power BI Premium is a SaaS (Software as a Service) product that allow to users to consume content through mobile applications, internally developed apps, or at the Power BI portal. Power BI Embedded is for ISVs who want to embed visuals into their applications.

Comment: This answer is just a cut-and-paste of a more complete answer previously posted.